# How to remove the last new line (\n)

Tags: java

I have the code below. the if condition is true and it goes into the line inside the IF but when I inspect answerText later, it still has the new line at the end

```
if(answerText.endsWith("\n")){
     answerText = answerText.substring(0, answerText.length()-2);           
}
```

Comment: @Adam's answer is so far the best one, but I suspect that you have other errors contributing to your problem.

Comment: The only thing wrong with the code you've posted is that it should be `length()-1`

Comment: How exactly to you inspect it? BTW, you remove one character more than you want, the second index is exclusive.

Answer (score 14):

```
answerText = answerText.trim()
```

> public String [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)
>
> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

Comment: deleted my answer in favor of this better answer. 1+

Comment: I'm aware this is a really old answer but in case someone is still looking for this: This doesn't answer the question! `trim()` removes ALL whitecharacters at the beginning AND the end of the string, which also inclused tabs, spaces,... OP was only asking about how to remove the last new line.

Answer (score 1):

```java
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripEnd( "text\n\n\n" , "\n" );
```

> Removes a substring only if it is at the end of a source string, otherwise returns the source string

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.